# iPhone Application Linking/Compile Errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on an iPhone application.  I added a new framework to my project, and this caused a bunch of linking errors, with the following error for each framework I'm using:

```
ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, missing required architecture i386 in file
```

This caused other errors, saying things like NSString did not exist.  I deleted and re-added all frameworks several times to no avail.  As another attempt to fix the problem, I copied all my source files to a new directory and created a new project.  When trying to compile in that project, I get the error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol .objc_class_name_${PROJECT_NAME}AppDelegate in /Users/nick/Documents/SVN/Programming/iPhone/${PROJECT_NAME}/newTrunk/${PROJECT_NAME}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.build/Objects-normal/i386/${PROJECT_NAME}AppDelegate-B70D3802A4DFAE4D.o and /Users/nick/Documents/SVN/Programming/iPhone/${PROJECT_NAME}/newTrunk/${PROJECT_NAME}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.build/Objects-normal/i386/${PROJECT_NAME}AppDelegate-B70D3802A4DFAE4D.o
```

(I've replaced parts of the above with ${PROJECT_NAME} because I'm not currently able to discuss specifics of the project.)

If anyone has any insights into either of the problems I'm experiencing, I would love to hear from you.

Comment: Was the framework designed to be used with the 3.1 firmware? Does the framework have any external dependencies?

Comment: Yes, the frameworks I'm using are for 3.1.  As far as I know, they don't have external dependencies.  Everything was working fine until I added a new framework, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It looks like you are building for Mac, not iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Which way did you use to add the framework?
Did you doubleclick the app in the left bar under Targets and link the library there?